# removing auto layout constraints for a view (and subviews) but keep the same frame positions

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, uipangesturerecognizer

Is there a way to 'flatten' a UIView and subviews? removing the auto layout constraints from them, but retaining their position as absolute CGRect values?

I would like to use a UIPanGestureRecogniser to move a UIView, but the autolayout is messing it up

Comment: You can either use the gesture recogniser to modify the constraints, or grab the computed frame and then deactivate the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I think Paul's comment should work. Take a look at the demo code below. When the dragging starts, I deactivate the constraints, and when it ends, the constraints are re-activated and at the same time gets new values from the new position of the dragged view.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var top: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var leading: NSLayoutConstraint?
    @IBOutlet weak var viewDrag: UIView!
    var panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer!

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.draggedView(_:)))
        viewDrag.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        viewDrag.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        
        viewDrag.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.top = viewDrag.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: self.viewDrag.frame.origin.y)
        self.leading = viewDrag.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: self.viewDrag.frame.origin.x)
        
        self.top?.isActive = true
        self.leading?.isActive = true
    }

    @objc func draggedView(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        viewDrag.center = CGPoint(x: viewDrag.center.x + translation.x, y: viewDrag.center.y + translation.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        
        if sender.state == .began {
            self.top?.isActive = false
            self.leading?.isActive = false
        } else if sender.state == .ended {
            self.top?.isActive = true
            self.leading?.isActive = true
            self.top?.constant = self.viewDrag.frame.origin.y
            self.leading?.constant = self.viewDrag.frame.origin.x
        }
    }
}
```